# Flutter: how to make my app work with every phone size?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

Beginner question: So I just finished my first app and was working with android studio and one emulator. After I tried a second one with different screen size, I noticed that some of the containers and fonts are not being displayed correctly. I used a helper class for the sizes https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil but I'm still facing some problems here and there. How can I make the app work correctly on all phones? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is not any fixed rule to test it out. But the way I do and recommend and many other people recommend is to test your app for both the largest screen size your app is compatible with and the smallest screen size compatible with your app.

Comment: There is no way to make a flutter app work with all screen sizes?! I can't believe it...

Comment: Are you using fixed height and width for everything?

Comment: Not even on iOS with auto layout you can get a "perfect" scale to every screen and look amazing. Will always require manual adjustments to make it 99% good on everything. Plus... Flutter can have any size you can imagine

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla how do I adjust my app so it's 99% good? doesn't that mean dealing with every single screen size?

Comment: @AasharWahla with the help of the class I mentioned, yes

Comment: You should make your layout dynamic. e.g using media query, fittedbox and expanded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimise widgets to different screen sizes, you could do the following:

```
     Container(
     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height > 300 ? 200 : 100 
)
```

This simply checks if the screen size is higher then 300, if yes set the height to 200, else to 100. You also can do that with the width.

Comment: So I have to go through the entire app and fix every single container? It's 30 thousand lines of code...

Comment: of course you can add an custom Container like this: `
Container CustomContainer(context) {
  return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height > 300 ? 200 : 100);
}
`.